# Selecting elements from lists of length 1

Tags: r, list

A string split operation 
`strsplit("name1.csv", "\\.")`(*) 
returns a list: `'"name1' 'csv"'`.

I know that I can select only the file name before extension like so:
`strsplit("name1.csv", "\\.")[[1]][1]`  (**)

But this was selected from the returned list from (*), which has length 1.

Why is that?

Comment: you extract the first list element with `[[` and the first element inside that list with `[`

Comment: Is it so because splitting a string into 2 substrings produces a list of 1 character vector, which should have length of 2?

Comment: the list length is the same as the numbeer of initial elements.  Suppose you have `v1 <- c("name1.csv", "name2.csv")` and then do strsplit, the length of list is 2 and the length of each element within the list is 2, 2 from which you select the first element.  so it is of length 1

Comment: This explained. Thanks! Not sure about the web of etiquettes but if you can put the comment into answer field, I can mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Thanks, that is fine.  I think there must be dupes for this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object being returned from the `strsplit` function is a list of character vector which can be figured out using the class command :

```
> class(strsplit("name1.csv", "\\."))
[1] "list"
> class(strsplit("name1.csv", "\\.")[[1]])
[1] "character"
```

The elements of the list can be accessed using `[[` and the elements of the character vector inside the list can be accessed using `[[]] [`.

The object returned by `strsplit` is a list of length 1 consisting of a character vector of length two as seen below:

```
> length(strsplit("name1.csv", "\\."))
[1] 1
> length(strsplit("name1.csv", "\\.")[[1]])
[1] 2
```